# Send user to Google Play and return after install

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Does anybody know a way I can return a user to my app after sending them to Google Play to install an app?

I'm using standard ACTION_VIEW with a "market://" Uri and I need to take them back to where they were in my app (as opposed to them hitting "open" in Google Play".

Essentially I need to go "back" as soon as Google Play has installed the app they were linked to, which requires Google Play to "finish()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Play referrals (Android Native Application Tracking)
When user installs the app you get a broadcast to your app.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/?hl=en#android-market-tracking

And [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-tracking)

Answer (score 0):

In my exp. it is not possible because if you call finish(() with intent.Then your activity also destroy.